# Vue 3: Cannot resolve "@vue/vue3-jest" module. on GitHub Actions

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, github-actions

When running my unit tests in GitHub actions after upgrading to Vue 3, I get the following error:

```
> vue-cli-service test:unit

● Validation Error:

  An unknown error occurred in @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest:

  Cannot resolve "@vue/vue3-jest" module. Please make sure you have installed "@vue/vue3-jest" as a dev dependency.
```

The GitHub actions script uses `npm ci` as its previous step to install dependencies, and the test command `vue-cli-service test:unit` works locally.

My package.json has:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.14.5",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.4.12",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.12",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.4.12",
    "@storybook/vue": "^6.4.12",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.31.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@testing-library/vue": "^6.4.2",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "latest",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@vue/cli-shared-utils": "^4.5.10",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/preload-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.4",
    ...
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    ...
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
    "jest-extended": "^0.11.5",
    "jest-junit": "^8.0.0",
    ...
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
  },
```

and my jest.config.js matching the [docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest) in using @vue/vue3-jest:

```
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
# Vue 2
npm install --save-dev @vue/vue2-jest@28 # (use the appropriate version)

yarn add @vue/vue2-jest@28 --dev



# Vue 3
npm install --save-dev @vue/vue3-jest@28 # (use the appropriate version)

yarn add @vue/vue3-jest@28 --dev
```